# ndk-build with android-ndk-r5b fails when compiling assembly files in OpenSSL

Tags: assembly, openssl, android-ndk

OPenssl with android-ndk-r5b compiles fine on Windows with cygwin if I change the case of the assembly files from .s to .S

However on Linux (Ubunti 10.0.4), with the same version of the NDK, I get the following error.

make: *** No rule to make target `externals/openssl-0.9.8h-android/crypto/0.9.9-dev/bn/armv4-mont.S', needed by`obj/local/armeabi/objs/crypto-static/0.9.9-dev/bn/armv4-mont.o'.  Stop.

If I revert the case of the file back from .S to .s (lowercase) on Ubuntu, I get this error.

mv: cannot stat `./obj/local/armeabi/objs/crypto-static/0.9.9-dev/bn/armv4-mont.o.d.org': No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/crypto-static/0.9.9-dev/bn/armv4-mont.o] Error 1

Is this a bug with the new Android NDK r5b release.? If so is there a fix or a workaround for this..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the NDK, already fixed.  See [this bug tracker entry](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15379).